# Searching for an object inside an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array, filled with arrays, each containing multiple objects. I want to see if my objects exists in there

Ive made a jsfiddle to keep it simple - https://jsfiddle.net/rgnoz31y/1/

Or if you want to just see my code, its below:

```
blackChains = [];

blackChains.push([{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 3}]);
blackChains.push([{x: 3, y: 4}, {x:4, y: 4}, {x:5, y: 4}]);

currentPiece = {x: 1, y: 3};

const isInChain = blackChains.map(g => g[{}]).includes(currentPiece);

console.log(isInChain);
```

It currently returns false, when it should be true

Comment: What do you think `g[{}]` will return?

Comment: isnt that just were its searching? the objects in the array in the array

Comment: `g[{}]` will return `undefined`. It is interpreted as `g["Object object"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Arrow functions, I assumed you are using ES6.

Using [Spreads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), I can create an array of all the Array Items https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

```
acc.push(...item);
```

`includes` would usually work, however it only works on call by reference, not call by value e.g. this would have failed:

```
console.log([{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 3}].includes(currentPiece));
```

[Some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns true, if at least one of the items matches the condition.  By changing the Item and Search Element into a JSON String, we can check by Value.

```js
blackChains = [];

blackChains.push([{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 3}]);
blackChains.push([{x: 3, y: 4}, {x:4, y: 4}, {x:5, y: 4}]);

currentPiece = {x: 1, y: 3};

const isInChain = blackChains.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push(...item);
  return acc;
}, []).some(item => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(currentPiece));

console.log(isInChain);
```

Comment: Just a pointer, `JSON.stringify` will remove any functions. Alternatively you can also try `JSON.stringify(blackChains).indexOf(JSON.stringify(currentPiece)) >=0`

Comment: Also you can try `blackChains.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(c), [])`

Answer (score 0):

As commented before,

> g[{}] will return undefined. It is interpreted as g["Object object"]

`blackChains.map(g => g[{}])` will return an array of length `n` with all as undefined.

You can use recursion to loop over `r` nested arrays and stop it when you get Objects.

```js
var blackChains = [];

blackChains.push([{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 3}]);
blackChains.push([{x: 3, y: 4}, {x:4, y: 4}, {x:5, y: 4}]);


var currentPiece = { x: 1, y: 3 };

function searchObjInArray(arr, search) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return arr.some(function(item) {
      return searchObjInArray(item, search)
    })
  } else if (typeof arr === "object") {
    var valid = true;
    for (var k in search) {
      valid = valid && search[k] === arr[k];
      if (!valid) break;
    }
    return valid;
  }
}

var isInChain = searchObjInArray(blackChains, currentPiece)
console.log("isInChain: ", isInChain);

currentPiece.y = 4;

isInChain = searchObjInArray(blackChains, currentPiece)
console.log("isInChain: ", isInChain);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. i accepted the other guys because he answered first and it was abit more short and sweet but i appriciate this, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Replace with:

```js
const isInChain = blackChains.findIndex(
  i => i.findIndex(a => a.x === currentPiece.x && a.y === currentPiece.y) > -1) > -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check key-value equality explicitly as shown below:

```js
blackChains = [];

blackChains.push([{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 3}]);
blackChains.push([{x: 3, y: 4}, {x:4, y: 4}, {x:5, y: 4}]);

currentPiece = {x: 1, y: 3};

const isInChain = blackChains.map(bc => !!bc.find(o => // return true a false for each index
  Object.keys(o).every(key => o[key] === currentPiece[key])));

console.log(isInChain);
```

Comment: `Object.is` won't be helpful here, because it's still compares object references, not their contents.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try with [`Array#filter()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIt4yth5zUAhULsI8KHYG0BFUQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHgB7IyOa22NG7kCsGZ1ldwMUmkiA&sig2=VMO6Od2Y5bt5UHGXEtgZ0g) and [`Array#find()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi454m3h5zUAhWDtY8KHZL6CbEQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffind&usg=AFQjCNEJXKz25jH7wLT1dX55f_XDZ9QiRg&sig2=aipPyECBn5LhGg-jnxRqgw) used find the match with `c` Array

```js
function check(c){
blackChains = [];
blackChains.push([{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 3}]);
blackChains.push([{x: 3, y: 4}, {x:4, y: 4}, {x:5, y: 4}]);
return blackChains.filter(a=> a.find(a=> a.x == c.x && a.y == c.y ))[0] ? true : false;
}
console.log(check({x: 1, y:3}))
console.log(check({x: 1, y:31}))
```

Comment: `Array.filter` will loop till end even if value is found. Try `Array.some`